# Unable to store Date values in php mysql table that are existing in excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel, date

Hi friends i have a php program where user can upload excel file and data w illbe stored in php database, it works as i expected but the problem is date stored in database is totally different from what i entered in excel

i have used the following codes to read the value from excel..

```
include("excel/reader.php");
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read($_POST['upload']);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$conn);
$a="TRUNCATE TABLE `sheet`";
mysql_query($a);
for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) 
{
$inv = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
$ds = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
$dosstr=strtotime($ds);
$dos=date('Y-m-d',$dosstr);
$ptname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
$bal = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
$proname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][5];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sheet (INV,DOS,PTNAME,BAL,PROV)
VALUES ('$inv','$dos','$ptname','$bal','$proname')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
header('location:exsheet2.php');
   ?>
```

i have the following dates stored in excel 
9/1/2014,
28/12/2013 ,
27/9/1991 ,
1/1/2015 ,
31/12/2014 ,
1/1/2012 ,
5/9/2001 .

but what is being stored in database is
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01 ,
1970-01-01.

please assist me with this issue thanks

```
for ($x = 2; $x <= count($data->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) 
{
$inv = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
$ds = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
echo $ds;
echo "<br>";
if(ctype_digit($ds))
{
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$dDate = date_create('1900-01-01');
$dDate = date_modify($dDate, '+'.($ds-2).' day');
if($dDate!="")
{
$dos = date_format($dDate,'Y-m-d');
echo "IF".$dos;
echo "<br>";
}
else
{ 
$dos=$ds; //not able to convert date so show it directly
echo "Else".$dos;
echo "<br>";
}
}
else 
{
$dos=$ds;
echo"if Else".$dos;
}

$ptname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
$bal = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
$proname = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][5];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sheet (INV,DOS,PTNAME,BAL,PROV)
VALUES ('$inv','$dos','$ptname','$bal','$proname')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: echo $ds; Paste the output

Comment: if i just print $ds i m getting the following output 41648,41636,33508,42005,42004,40909,37139

Comment: So you are not getting the dates after parsing the excel. isn't it?

Comment: yes you r right,, i have even changed the cell format in excel but no use

Comment: @manikandan This is the problem of PHP date functions, Excel returning date as integer which are no of days, not timestamp. See my answer for explanation.

Comment: @manikandan according to your edited question/updated code, see my edited answer now... :)  | Here just validate that all data is correct and all PHP function working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the actual problem is in your date function. You cannot use these php functions coz these are for unix timestamp. And excel returns date as `integer` values. **The no of days since 1/1/1900, including first and last day**

so replace these lines:

```
$dosstr=strtotime($ds);
$dos=date('Y-m-d',$ds);
```

to

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$dDate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '1900-01-01');
$dDate=date_add($dDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string(($ds-2).' days'));
$dos=$dDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

PHP 5.2 version:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$dDate = date_create('1900-01-01');
if($dDate = date_modify($dDate, '+'.($ds-2).' day'))
    $dos = date_format($dDate,'Y-m-d');
else $dos=$ds; //not able to convert date so show it directly
```

OR safe code:

```
if(ctype_digit($ds)){
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
   $dDate = date_create('1900-01-01');
   $dDate = date_modify($dDate, '+'.($ds-2).' day');
   if($dDate!="") //if($dDate) //is_a($dDate,'DateTime')) //get_class($dDate)=='DateTime' //if ($dDate instanceof DateTime) 
       $dos = date_format($dDate,'Y-m-d');
   else $dos=$ds;
}
else $dos=$ds;
```

---

And reason of problem of getting incorrect date which have day greater than `12` is: You have dates stored in excel as Indian dates. But your laptop's default date and time are US or UK...

you need to change it first (in Region and Language Settings).

1) click on time shown at right of taskbar, in windows.

2) under the calendar you'll see a link "change date and time settings". open it.

3) click "change date and time" button -> then click **change calendar settings** link.

4) probably two more window will open. close the **customized format** window and go to "Region and Language".

5) Select "English(India)" as Format and "dd-MM-yyyy" as short date.

6) click OK. Then try again, if any problem, comment.

Comment: i tried this but it is returning he following error:tFatal error: Call to undefined function date_create_from_format() in C:\wamp\www\dbpro file\one\exsheet.php on line 20

Comment: @manikandan which php version you are working on, this function is supported by `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`. If you have lesser version then: If you can upgrade then do it OR tell me i'll find something which works for your version.

Comment: oh i am using PHP Version 5.2.2

Comment: can u pls assist me with this issue. i am in the middle of my college project , i cannot complete my project without this.

Comment: @manikandan yes. but problem is that I have given four PHP datetime functions `date_create_from_format()`, `date_add()`, `date_interval_create_from_date_string()` and `date->format()`. in which first three are supported by PHP-5.3 | first function can be replace by `$dDate = date_create('1900-01-01');`. Now we need to find the replacement of two functions of next line.

Comment: i appreciate for your help buddy. i am also searching for replacement from my side

Comment: it is returning error Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\dbpro file\one\exsheet.php on line 22

Comment: @manikandan change that(last) line to `$dos = date_format($dDate,'Y-m-d');` and tell me the result. | if not work then echo $dDate / var_dump($dDate) and tell me what's the output.

Comment: tried but not working, $dDate is returning blank space

Comment: @manikandan Update your code in Question. so that I can check error, its working here... See a little change in my answer...

Comment: @manikandan I can see you are trying other things also..:) Good. Your code is OK, there may be `$ds` is blank/or not an integer. that's why `date_modify` function is not working. Coz, you are in a for loop, if in any row there is problem with `$ds`, your PHP page will give fetal error. So check `$dDate` is not blank, and echo `$ds` to see is there any problem in any for loop. check my code again.

Comment: for me its not working dude it showing 0000-00-00 for all the dates.. i have changed the excel cell format would that be the reason for the wrong output

Comment: what PHP version you are using dude

Comment: `PHP 5.4`. If `$ds` is echos `41648, 41636, 33508, 42005, 42004, 40909, 37139` then my code will convert it to proper MySQL dates. 0000-00-00 will come in database when you are inserting blank/0 means not a proper date. If PHP code properly coverts the `$ds` then your problem will be solved. We need to look at that code only. Be ensure that `$ds` is equal to `41648`. Try running loop one time only, check it works for first record or not? what's the `$ds` `$dDate` and `$dos` for first loop? Do some debugging. :)

Comment: i've tried as much as i could, let me start it again tomorrow, anyway thank you so much dude u helped a lot... and Happy New Year Buddy

Comment: Hi Adarsh Now $ds is Printing 41648, 41636, 33508, 42005, 42004, 40909, 37139 but if($dDate!="") is not executing can u pls have a look at my updated Question

Answer (score 0):

Print the sql query and check what values are inserted in the query. The date format should be "Y-m-d".

Comment: yes John i tried but  the same wrong value is getting printed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the formatting from the date column of the excel sheet. Then try again. This may help you [PHP Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader always reading date as Nov 30, 1999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882040/php-spreadsheet-excel-reader-always-reading-date-as-nov-30-1999), http://dirtyhandsphp.blogspot.in/2012/03/phpexcelreader-uses-and-problems.html

Comment: i tried it is partially working for me if date is below 12 it is showing incorrect dates (ex 25/01/2014 is in excel it is printed as 2014-01-25 in browser but 1/2/2014 is stored as 2014-01-03 in database similarly 8/9/2000 stored as 2000-08-10)